# Azure Policy "SSH access from the Internet should be blocked" with effect deny

Tags: azure, azure-policy

My goal: Prevent VMs being accessed via SSH by *denying* NSG rules which allow inbound traffic via the port 22.

I first tried to write a custom policy by myself and then to re-write this policy: [SSH access from the Internet should be blocked](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F2c89a2e5-7285-40fe-afe0-ae8654b92fab). But in both cases, when I create a VM, the associated NSG will still be created with open SSH port.

My policies act like they have the effect *audit*, since they do not immediately stop the request of the resource (VM, NSG) but non-compliance in the *Compliance* is displayed later in the Portal. But then, of course, it is too late, and the resources are already in place and running.

Thanks for your help!

Update:

Rephrasing the question: Why does Azure not provide the effect *deny* in the first place?

The entire policy (same as the policy linked above, except the effect *deny*) as requested by @KenWMSFT:

```
"if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules",
            "field": "type"
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "equals": "Allow",
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/access"
              },
              {
                "equals": "Inbound",
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/direction"
              },
              {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "equals": "*",
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange"
                  },
                  {
                    "equals": "22",
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange"
                  },
                  {
                    "equals": "true",
                    "value": "[if(and(not(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'))), contains(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),22),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),22)), 'false')]"
                  },
                  {
                    "count": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                      "where": {
                        "equals": "true",
                        "value": "[if(and(not(empty(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')))), contains(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),22),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),22)) , 'false')]"
                      }
                    },
                    "greater": 0
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                      "notEquals": "*"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                      "notEquals": "22"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "equals": "*",
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix"
                  },
                  {
                    "equals": "Internet",
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix"
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                      "notEquals": "*"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                      "notEquals": "Internet"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the policy you are using so we can see your settings

Comment: have you tried the effect of disabled?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @KenWMSFT I provided the link to the policy. The only change is that I use the effect *deny*. But sure, I can post the entire policy if it is the common approach here.

Comment: @user6932954 Do you really think that the effect *disabled* has the intended effect? According to the docs it is a way "to disable a single assignment" and, as far as I understood, not to disable the resource request.

Comment: At first glance I would expect this policy to deny the deployment of security rules but allow the deployment of the virtual machine. Azure sees the NSG security rules as being separate resources than the virtual machine. For this type of policy I'm not sure if the deny effect is possible.  However you could deployIfNotExist NSG security rules to block port 22 if they do not exist.  This would allow the deployment to continue and override deployment settings which open port 22 to SSH traffic.

Comment: I also expect that the VM is deployed but the NSG rule not. But the NSG is deployed with the rule. Why do you think that is not possible for "this type", what type of policy do we have here in comparison to others? I like the _deployIfNoTExist_ approach, though. Seems like a nice workarround. I will test that.

Comment: @bogg securityRules can also be specified as an array property on the *Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups* resource type.  If you add conditions (or a separate policy) to target that type and block non-compliant security rules from begin added to the array (using alias Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*]), that should work.